# Apple Search Ads campaign attribution in Firebase after iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics, iad

I started running ad campaigns using Apple Search Ads and I'm interested what are the implications after iOS 14 and the whole ATT.

In the Google Analytics docs, it is said that I only need to import the iAdsFramework and the attribution will happen.

Looking at the iAds documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iad/setting_up_apple_search_ads_attribution), I see that IDFA is not tracked.

Do I still need to [request tracking authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency) from my users?

I only want to find out how many new users are organic or acquired from Apple Search Ads.

Comment: Do you have the answer?  It seems Appmetrica is better, since it supports AdServices as well as iAd. Apple Search Ads doesn't need SKAdNetwork. @Andrei Matei

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the same topic, but in our case I wonder if it works with SKAdNetwork in order to not request the IDFA

Comment: Apple Search Ads doesn't need SKAdNetwork. It users AdServices. @Patricio Hervas